# Full width at half maximum of the sum of two Lorentzian distributions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

When I have a Lorentzian distribution (centered at xc and with area c1):

```
L1[x_] := c1*1/π*(1/2*S1)/((x - xc)^2 + (1/2*S1)^2)
```

then the full width at half maximum (FWHM) is simply `S1`. Suppose now that I have two Lorentzian distributions:

```
L1[x_] := c1*1/π*(1/2*S1)/((x - xc)^2 + (1/2*S1)^2)
L2[x_] := c2*1/π*(1/2*S2)/((x - xc)^2 + (1/2*S2)^2)
```

What is the FWHM of `L[x]`, sum of `L1` and `L2`?

```
L[x_] := L1[x] + L2[x]
```

Comment: This seems more like a [math.se] question, rather than about the computing software *Mathematica*.

Comment: it is indeed a Mathematics question, but I am interested in how to compute it, symbolically, with Mathematica. I should have explained this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
distr1 = CauchyDistribution[xc, S1/2];

PDF[distr1, x] // Simplify

(*  (2*S1)/(Pi*(S1^2 + 4*(x - xc)^2))  *)

distr2 = CauchyDistribution[xc, S2/2];

PDF[distr2, x] // Simplify

(*  (2*S2)/(Pi*(S2^2 + 4*(x - xc)^2))  *)
```

The constraints on the parameters are

```
assume = And[
   DistributionParameterAssumptions[distr1],
   DistributionParameterAssumptions[distr2]] // Simplify

(*  xc ∈ Reals && S1 > 0 && S2 > 0  *)
```

The distribution of the sum of two Lorentzian variates is

```
distrSum = TransformedDistribution[l1 + l2,
  {l1  \[Distributed] distr1, l2  \[Distributed] distr2}]

(*  CauchyDistribution[2*xc, S1/2 + S2/2]  *)
```

The maximum value is

```
max = Assuming[assume,
  Maximize[PDF[distrSum, x], x] //
   Simplify]

(*  {2/(Pi*(S1 + S2)), {x -> 2*xc}}  *)
```

Verifying that this where the derivative is zero

```
D[PDF[distrSum, x], x] /. max[[2]]

(*  0  *)
```

The full width half maximum is

```
fwhm = Assuming[assume,
  Abs[Subtract @@ (x /.
        Solve[PDF[distrSum, x] == max[[1]]/2, x, Reals] //
       Simplify)] //
    Simplify]

(*  S1 + S2  *)
```

**EDIT:** The distribution of the weighted sum of two Lorentzian variates is

```
distrSum2 = Assuming[assume,
  TransformedDistribution[a*l1 + b*l2,
   {l1  \[Distributed] distr1, l2  \[Distributed] distr2}]]

(*  CauchyDistribution[a xc + b xc, (a S1)/2 + (b S2)/2]  *)
```

Assuming that the weights are positive

```
assume2 = assume && a > 0 && b > 0

(*  xc ∈ Reals && S1 > 0 && S2 > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0  *)
```

The maximum value is

```
max2 = Assuming[assume2,
  Maximize[PDF[distrSum2, x], x] //
   Simplify]

(*  {2/(a π S1 + b π S2), {x -> (a + b) xc}}  *)
```

Verifying that this where the derivative is zero

```
Assuming[assume2,
 D[PDF[distrSum2, x], x] /. max2[[2]] //
  Simplify]

(*  0  *)
```

The full width half maximum is

```
fwhm2 = Assuming[assume2,
  Abs[Subtract @@ (x /.
        Solve[PDF[distrSum2, x] == max2[[1]]/2, x, Reals] //
       Simplify)] // Simplify]

(*  a S1 + b S2  *)
```

Comment: Inserting values in the function, that doesn't seem to be the right answer. In my example that would be 3.4.

Comment: @Feyre - you cannot get the distribution for the sum of two random variates by adding their PDFs.

Comment: You're right, I misread this. I was confused as was with the weird solution.

Comment: is this result valid only for Cauchy distributions with area=1? What happens if I change their relative areas?

Comment: @Luigi - then presumably you went the distribution: `distrSum = TransformedDistribution[a*l1 +b* l2,
  {l1  \[Distributed] distr1, l2  \[Distributed] distr2}]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon yes indeed. But when I try to calculate where this distribution has a maximum, I get a result for all the conditions (eg a== 0 && b > 0, ...). How to tell Mathematica that I am only interested in the case where both a and b >0?